# Count the number of constants in a DSolve solution

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations

I'm solving a system of ODEs using `DSolve`. I'm having a hard time keeping track of the number of undetermined constants that are still left in the solution. Is there a way to count or list the constants (`C[1]`, `C[2]`, etc.) that are present in a typical `DSolve` solution? This would give me a lot of insight into which boundary conditions I might need to supply, change or rethink, in order to solve for the constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
sol = DSolve[{y'[x] == x^2 y[x], z'[x] == 5 z[x]}, {y[x], z[x]}, x]
```

> {{y[x] -> E^(x^3/3) C[1], z[x] -> E^(5 x) C[2]}}

```
Cases[sol, C[x_] -> C[x], Infinity]
```

> {C[1], C[2]}

or just

```
Cases[sol, C[_], Infinity]
```

Comment: Or just `Cases[sol, C[_], Infinity]`. In some cases you might want to add `//Union`